# How do I enable Mantaflow in Blender?

Tags: add-on, physics, fluid-simulation

I have been using the internal Blender fluid system for a while now and it has been very frustrating so I'm hoping it'll be better with Mantaflow.

How do I enable Mantaflow in Blender?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mantaflow is not in Master yet so you have two options for now:

1. You can grab a build with Mantaflow here: http://graphicall.org/
2. You can build [Mantaflow Branch](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/fluid-mantaflow/) by yourself from sources: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender